# SonarQube rule - "title" should be present in all pages

Tags: xhtml, sonarqube, sonarqube5.2

The rule **"title" should be present in all pages** is present on the Web Profile of SonarQube.  I understand the reason why it exists but I am facing a situation where nothing can be done - so far - to avoid its violation.  Let me explain...

When developing using primefaces if the header in xhtml is declared as just "head" tag it does not include some artificats that belongs to the primefaces framework.  So, a xhtml like is required

```
<h:head>
<title>something</title>
....
<h:/head>
```

But this violates the rule I mentioned in bold.
Maybe because it checks html and xhtml files... not sure.

My thought about that was:

- to edit this rule so it would recognize as a complaint code a h:head, or;
- change the extension files this rule scans, or;
- as last case disable it;

Any ideas about what to do and how to do it?

Comment: The `h:head` is jsf, not PrimeFaces, or are ypu saying the PrimeFaces head renderer behaves differently compared tt]o the plain jsf one (like when not including the primefaces jar). And you can always put the title tag in any page. Don't see the actual problem

Comment: Irrelevant since primefaces is a set o JSF components and the underlying tech is JSF.  

The fact is that the filter is not matching the pattern with the code and the code produces - after rendering - a head / title nesting html code.  And also I can not change my xhtml code to write directly head instead of h:head.

Comment: Sorry, but I have no clue what you are saying... Most likely in a response to BalusC that he removed after your response... Correct?